# Position Of Views in Android vs iOS?

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c, xml

I am new to Android development. I have been working in iOS since long. As in iOS when we want to put VIEW on xib on some exact position, we simply put it there, drag it up to that point.

For example say Two buttons at lower area in iOS, which look like below
[image]

As, I simply want them in middle, I will put them their. as below

[image]

Now same thing in Android environment, I go for following code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/db1_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myAwesomeTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Veer Suthar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myAwesomeTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:layout_below="@id/myAwesomeTextView"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/myAwesomeTextView1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
            android:onClick="buttonPressed"
            android:text="Button One" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
            android:onClick="buttonPressed"
            android:text="Button Two" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It shows Activity Screen, like below

[image]

Now If I want to drag buttons, using **GRAPHICAL LAYOUT**, I can't move them as I want, and for spacing to put them into lower area, I need to put extra **TextView** .

Is there any better way to organise Android Activity GUI properly, like iOS?

Comment: Now, do you want it in the middle or at then bottom of the screen?

Comment: Honestly android Graphical layout is not very good to work like the xCode. I personally prefer to do it by code in Android.

Comment: Not exactly I want in middle, I want to drag and drop on Graphical View, as I can do in iOS. Can I do it in Android?

Comment: @T.V., I agree with you. As far as, I saw it, There are layout, There are restrictions, its not smooth as iOS is.

Comment: @AndroidCheeta besides not being smooth as XCode working with the graphical layout adds a lot of garbage to your xml code, In my opinion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give you a brief example, since Android graphical layout is not as smooth as XCode.

To accomplish what you need, centering the two buttons in the screen, you can use a XML code like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/button_one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button One"/>

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/button_two"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button Two"/>
     </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The trick is to use `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` for the only component that you want to be centered in the screen all other components can use that one for reference to be placed in the screen.

For example

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myAwesomeTextView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:layout_above="@+id/layout_center"
    android:text="Veer Suthar"/>
```

This is one way for doing this, you can always find a better and more comprehensible way to do things.
Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `LinearLayout`:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
```

Childs in a `RelativeLayout` can be "glued" to a particular position relative to the parent layout or to other elements in the same layout using the xml tags listed here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html